# ActiveRecord access relation gives stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image
    belongs_to :album

    def image
        if self.image
            return self.image
        elsif self.album
            return self.album.image
        else 
            return nil
        end
    end
    # …Other code
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :image
    has_many :songs
    # …Other code
end
```

Songs might not have an image assigned, and in that case calling aSong.image should return the song's album's image. Accessing instances in the console work as expected, but the first line in `image` returns a `stack level too deep` error, and I can't figure out why.

My view code:

```
<% @user.songs.each do |s| %>
    <div class='GridItem'>
      <%= image_tag("#{ s.image.path }", alt: s.image.caption) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your `image` function keeps calling itself endlessly if image is set:

```
def image
    if self.image
        return self.image
    ...
end
```

You get that error when it has called itself enough to fill up the stack.

Comment: yeah, and you use `read_attribute` instead http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/read_attribute

Comment: Don, that was indeed the issue, thanks! Phoet, for some reason `read_attribute(:image)` was giving me `nil`. It seems to work fine when I replace it with `super`, so now my image method is simply `return super || self.album.image || nil`